# Mongoose Populate() doesn't return anything, it just stays stuck

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 Schemas, one is for Questions and the other is for Themes

It's a one to many relationship, where theme_id references the id for the Theme

It works great but thene I try to use populate to get the theme info from the id it just doesn't do anything, literally

I am making an API so when I hit /questions/:id with the respective id of the question, nothing happens Postman just freezes and the server does nothing

This is the Question Schema:

```js
const questionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    question: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: { unique: true }
    },
    answers: [{
        name: String,
        is_true: Boolean
    }],
    theme_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'themes'
    }
});

const Question = module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);
```

This is the Themes Schema:

```js
const themeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: { unique: true }
    },
    relation: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

});

const Theme = module.exports = mongoose.model('Theme', themeSchema);
```

This is how my get question method:

```js
exports.getQuestion = (req, res, next) => {
    Question.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate('theme_id')
    .exec((err, question) => {
        if(err) return err;
        console.log(question);

        res.json(question);
    })
}
```

When I do

```js
populate('theme_id')
```

Nothing happens as described above

When I do

```js
populate('theme') //or any other string, it doesn't matter
```

I get the theme_id field from MongoDB but it's not populated, it's just the ID of the theme

Been stuck here for a while now, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongoose give reference using `ref:"ModelName"`

```
 const questionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
       ...
      theme_id: {                                   //<--  use this key in populate 
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Theme'                             // <-- model name here 
        }
    });

    const Question = module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);
```

and populate using field name in schema using : `populate('field_name')`

in your case : `populate('theme_id')`

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in your `ObjectId` reference .

Change `theme_id` reference to

```
theme_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Theme'
    }
```

Then

```
populate('theme_id')
```

You can read more at [Mongoose v5.6.13: Query Population](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)